# Can I initiate an action on Google Home from another application without a voice command?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I'm not sure if this is already possible. Can I have another application initiate an action to Google Home instead of having a person initiating by talking to it? For example: I wanted to have Smartthings IFTTT asking Google Home to play something. A couple cases below:

CASE 1: If I'm home and alarm armed and front door open then Smartthings will call Google Home for it to say: Front Door Opened

CASE 2: When the presence sensor detects I arrive Google Home greets me and ask if I would like to play anything.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. Right now, Google Home doesn't have notifications or asynchronous messaging. And while it is useful in several cases, it is also very likely that there would be a lot of over-use of the notification system which would reduce its usability.

Comment: Thank you... This is very unfortunate. Just out of curiosity, how can over-use reduce usability? Its a personal system and only the applications you run would call it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the device talking via google cast, but only within your home network. If you want to trigger it from the outside you will need to poke a hole into your firewall or use ngrok or the bst proxy and setup a "listener" that takes the event and sends a text to the device.

Comment: Interesting... do u have an example of how to do it? any reference? Thanks!

Comment: Here is a simple one (node.js): https://github.com/noelportugal/google-home-notifier. The device name, in the example, has to be the long id, not this short name, you gave to the device. You can find it with the IP address.