# How to develop skill with Google Home except voice input?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I am new to Google Assistant having one query about Google assistant with Google Home,

How to enable Google Home to be enable to speak without voice input? Is this possible to give input by any other way  except voice and take output from Google Home in voice format?

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to doing a notification or push event through the Google Home, and this is not currently available. Interactions using Google Home and the Actions on Google API require the user to initiate the conversation and the reply to go through the same channel as the input.

Comment: I don't understand why the answers are saying this is equivalent to notifications. To me it seems like the asker is interested in non-verbal interaction, not prompts initiated by Google home.  I'm interested in this question because I want to build accessible technology to enable people to interact with Google Home without using touch screen OR voice. Based on what I'm finding it doesn't seem like it's possible

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that yet, if you are asking for automating the triggering of actions through a rest api for example and then the google home just starts answering, there is no rest api for that but this will be the proactive assistant functionality.

In Google IO 2017, they introduced a new concept coming to the Google assistant which is proactive functionality, some calls it notifications, which is allowing the google assistant to start the conversation with the user, to give him info about the traffic for example if he has to be in a meeting in time.

but they announced neither a time frame nor any information about it.
so if this is what you are looking for, you just have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

There's another answer that suggests you can programmatically synthesize speech audio and send it directly to Google Home on the user's behalf. You can use whatever input mechanism you want, as long as under the hood you produce audio that Google Home recognizes and can act on.

[Can I initiate an action on Google Home from another application without a voice command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338816/can-i-initiate-an-action-on-google-home-from-another-application-without-a-voice)

It might seem strange to have a robot talking to a robot, but it opens up the possibility of users being able to type "commands" using natural language, then assign those commands to whatever trigger they want. Could be great for non-verbal folks or people with privacy concerns related to microphones.

[edit] I've since done more research and it looks like interfacing directly to Assistant (rather than through Google Home) does allow non-verbal integration: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/